# RHEL7; split a file into equal parts in parallel

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

Is it possible to run the linux `split` command with GNU `parallel` to speed up the splitting of the file?

Read a compressed file, and split it into some equal parts either by line count or filesize.

I'm trying as follows:

```
zcat file.gz | parallel --pipe --block 2000M 'gzip > {#}.gz'
```

Comment: Almost certainly not. The .gz format relies on a "dictionary of abbreviations", which are only emitted as needed, depending on the contents of the file being compressed. All the parallel processes need to see all of the dictionary, but only get some part of the data. That cannot be done, because they are intrinsically determined by previous data.

Comment: Actually, a simpler restriction: GNU/Parallel works by distributing "lines" to different threads. .gz files are not in lines. In fact, they are not even in bytes. The algorithm uses variable-length tokens, starting at 9 bits and switching to the next longer token (10, 11, 12 ... bits) every time the token lookup becomes full.

Comment: Could you put into words what your `zcat` and your `gzip` are doing in your question? Because your command line makes no sense at all, `| |` isn't even a valid shell construct, and I had to guess what you wanted to do. I **assume** you want to 1. decompress the input file, 2. write the uncompressed data into multiple files of equal size. **Is that correct**, Abhishek?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Uncompress a large gz file; partition it equally and compress each part separately.

Answer (score 1):

No. First of all, splitting files is IO bound, not CPU bound, very likely, so adding more CPU to the problem doesn't help.

gzip decompression itself could be parallelized¹ – use `unpigz --stdout` instead of `zcat`. But again, I doubt this really speeds up things significantly, since the bottleneck is writing data to files.

Splitting the output of a pipe itself is inherently sequential process, so parallelizing makes no sense and isn't even theoretically possible.

So, the fastest you can do is going to be

```bash
SIZE=10G # 10 GB output splits
unpigz --stdout | split -b ${SIZE} - outputfile_suffix_
```

---

¹ In fact, decompression *can't* actually be parallelized – it's again inherently sequential, but aside from the decompression thread, the checksum calculation and IO handling are done in separate threads in `unpigz`, leading to (often) an ever so slightly increased throughput.

Comment: could you please see my updated question now. I have tried this method and it seems a little faster than regular split

Comment: that makes no sense. Things are still sequential, inherently. Also, it's still not clear what you want to do. Please see my comment under your question and **answer** it.

Answer (score 0):

> could you please see my updated question now... I have tried this method and it **seems a little faster**

you are likely observing *disk caching* where the linux operating system has already read your `file.gz` from **disk** which is what is taking the time; with the file already stored in RAM things are much faster.  From a cold boot if the very fist thing you do after logging in is to try to split your file, however you are doing it, will seem like it takes the longest amount of time - because from cold boot that `file` has not been read from disk yet.  Once you've done that or anything else to have caused that `file` to get loaded from disk into RAM then whatever operations on it will be much faster.

This can mess with you, depending on the speed of your system, amount of ram (16gb, 32gb, 768gb), the size of your file, and the type of disk.

From experience on servers that used older spinning 7200 rpm HDD's instead of SSD's, having a `file.tar` of 10gb in size, could see a delay of **minutes** because of disk I/O on first access of the file.

*no, I don't think you can parallelize on the split coreutils command.*

If your **goal** is to work with some file and have things run as fast as possible - **create a *ramdisk***.

```
mkdir /scratch
mount -t tmpfs -o size=100g tmpfs /scratch
cp /from_wherever/file.gz /scratch
# this copy from disk to /scratch will be the initial time penalty.
# adjust size=?g accordingly, needs to be less than system ram
```

Once there on *ramdisk* subsequent operations will always be *fast*.  Realize this is RAM and will be lost on reboot, so `cp   /scratch/your_output   /back_to_wherever_on_disk` when done.

Answer (score 0):

If your file had not been compressed: Yes.

```
parallel --pipepart -a bigfile --block 2G gzip '>{#}'
```

I have the feeling you later want to process all the parts in parallel, in which case I recommend you do not split `bigfile` into temporary files, but you simply use GNU Parallel directly:

```
parallel --pipepart -a bigfile --block -1 myprocess data from stdin
```

It will chop `bigfile` into 1 part per CPU core and process them in parallel.